# How to use my own Docker image with GitLab CI?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

I want to use this Docker image:

https://cloud.docker.com/u/steevanb/repository/docker/steevanb/php-code-sniffs

From this Dockerfile:

https://github.com/steevanb/docker-php-code-sniffs/blob/master/Dockerfile

Locally, i use it like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

readonly PROJECT_DIR=$(realpath $(dirname $(realpath $0))/..)

docker run \
    --rm \
    -e PHPCS_PARAMETERS="--warning-severity=0 --ignore=/var/phpcs/var,/var/phpcs/vendor/" \
    -e PHPCS_BOOTSTRAP=/var/phpcs.bootstrap.php \
    -v ${PROJECT_DIR}:/var/phpcs:ro \
    -v ${PROJECT_DIR}/phpcs.bootstrap.php:/var/phpcs.bootstrap.php:ro \
    steevanb/php-code-sniffs:2.0.9
```

I don't understand how i can use it in Gitlab CI, with same parameters?

I've tried some things, like that:

```
phpcs:
    image:
        name: steevanb/php-code-sniffs:2.0.9
        entrypoint: ["/var/steevanb/php-code-sniffs/vendor/bin/phpcs", "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/project/user/src"]
    # don't need it, everything is done by overloading entrypoint
    script: echo $CI_PROJECT_DIR
```

But i have this error, seems $CI_PROJECT_DIR is not replaced with the expected value:

```
RROR: The file "$CI_PROJECT_DIR/project/user/src" does not exist.
```

Comment: What do you try to achieve? Please provide more information to us.

Comment: i want to call same `docker run ...` with Gitlab CI. I have a lot of errors when i try to do it, i can't write here all things i've tried it will be too long ;)

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gableroux/gitlab-ci-example-docker/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml check this example. things to understand form example, how to divide pipeline in stages , how to run docker commands and how to run on a particular branch.In case you want to run on particular runner looks for  **tags** in gitlab doc.  Hope this will help you to structure your pipline.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use your own image in default runners, you need to put `image` In the beginning of `.gitlab-ci.yml`, you should write it like:

```
image: python:alpine

before_script:
  - pip install mkdocs
...
```

Comment: it's not enough, see my example ;) i need to add some parameters to docker run, and i can't do it with `image` configuration.

Comment: Well, if I were you, I would write a new Dockerfile, use ```ADD``` and ```ENV``` to put the necessary files/environment variables into the image, push that into Dockerhub and use it like that if you want to use default runners.

Comment: i can't: i will not create a new image who contains my source code for each commit made. why can't i simply use a generic image, and add my parameters, with GitLab CI ? i had no problems with CircleCI before

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gitlab `CI/CD` you can use your image by uploading the images to docker hub.

**Steps to produce docker image:**
1.compose a **Docker** file in your local machine. 
2.build a docker image using that docker file. 
3.name the docker image, create or login to docker hub
4.publish the image to you docker repository.

Reference: [click here](https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-build-an-image-with-the-dockerfile/)

Comment: my image is realdy on dockerhub: https://cloud.docker.com/u/steevanb/repository/docker/steevanb/php-code-sniffs

Answer (score 0):

You can pass environment variables using either GitLab Secret Variables (set in the project settings) or by specifying variables in `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

See [GitLab CI YAML Variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#variables) documentation.

For example, in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` you may be able to specify:

```
variables:
  PHPCS_PARAMETERS: --warning-severity=0 --ignore=/var/phpcs/var,/var/phpcs/vendor/
  PHPCS_BOOTSTRAP: PHPCS_BOOTSTRAP=/var/phpcs.bootstrap.php

image: steevanb/php-code-sniffs:2.0.9

your_job:
  script:
  - your_script
```

In this example, the variables and image are set globally. You can also set both of these within each job rather than globally.